# OCR using Android Webcam Without Play Services

Tags: android, ocr, native

I am developing a custom device using a custom controller with Android 4.2. I need to take a picture and capture the text in the picture.
Play Store has not been developed for this controller and I need to find a basic source code to help me do this.

I tried using things like tesseract from the samples, but does not work. Am not much of an Android Appliction Guy and have thus far worked in C /C++, Python etc.

Need to Resolve this real soon.

Thanks and Regards

Neeraj.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? And why didn't it work? Please add code to your question

Answer (score 0):

you could give https://libraries.io/github/zxing/zxing a try.
This library is stand alone and won't need play libraries.

When you specify your problem, I can provide you with better suggestions